# Absolute and conditional convergence of a series with $\sin(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have to explore absolute and conditional convergence of this function series

[image]

I tried to find $a(n)$ and $a(n+1)$ terms of the series and then divide it and take a limit. But I've got nothing. Uppermost I also have to find a module of a(n)/a(n+1). to explore absolute and conditional convergence. Please, help me solve this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The $\;p$-series test tells us that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^p}\;\;\;\text{converges iff}\;\;p>1\;\ldots$$

Besides the above: what conditional or whatever series? This is **always** a positive series.

Comment: Sin(x) must be <= 1. so the series divergent. Right?

Comment: Indeed so, @user140810...and more than "must": it simply *is* .